# importing Network module for clearCookies

Tags: react-native

I was needing to `clearCookies` and found a hidden/undocumented function - https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/26684cf3adf4094eb6c405d345a75bf8c7c0bf88/Libraries/Network/RCTNetworking.android.js

I am able to access it like this:

```
import RCTNetworking from 'RCTNetworking'
console.log('RCTNetworking:', RCTNetworking.clearCookies);
```

It works, but is it correct? Will `import RCTNetworking from 'RCTNetworking'` work guranteed?

I thought it would be more safe to import from `NativeModules` like this:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native'
console.log('Networking:', NativeModules.Networking.clearCookies);
```

However this imports the whole `NativeModules` which has a bunch of other stuff. Wouldn't this be bad? Or does tree shakingng in production remove all the stuff I don't use from `NativeModules`?

Is there another way to access `clearCookies`? Is this documented anywhere?

Comment: Can you suggest of a way to check if it is removing cookies or not? It runs fine for me too. But the cookies for Instagram do not get removed.

Comment: There is a react-native-cookies module you can use to print out whats in the cookies - https://github.com/joeferraro/react-native-cookies

Comment: `react-native-cookies` does not work with RN 0.60 or above.

Comment: @Noitidart have you found any proper solution for clearing cookies in react native webview ?

Comment: @KishanBharda I think you can just clear cookies injecting a script and using regular javascript.

Answer (score 1):

I imported `RCTNetworking` like this: `var RCTNetworking = require("RCTNetworking");` This import is guaranteed to work on all platforms.
I couldn't find any documentation for `RCTNetworking` nor for the `clearCookies()` function

Comment: Were you able to use `clearCookies` as if it were a global?

Comment: Thanks very much I will try this out then accept solution.

Comment: I am so sorry, I just found that I actually did import `RCTNetworking`. I will update my answer

Comment: No problem thanks for sharing! How about my import style in the OP, is that not guranteed?

Comment: It should be guaranteed

Comment: Can anyone share the final solution? I've imported `RCTNetworking` with the `require()` syntax. Called `RCTNetworking.clearCookies(callback)`. It runs and works fine but doesn't clear cookies. I am using it to remove cookies stored by Instagram so that different users can login with the same device. Before this I was using `react-native-cookies` but it does not work on RN 0.60